# doesn't draw with onload()

Tags: javascript, canvas

Draws the little white rect  but not the image why is it like this and how to fix it.

```
var imageReady = false;
img = new Image(); 
img.src = 'player.png'; 
img.onload = loaded();

function loaded() { 
imageReady = true;
redraw(); 
}

function redraw() {
    //ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    //ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

    if (imageReady) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(10,10,10,10);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 5, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share more of your code? Im assuming you change imageRead in the onload of img. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `loaded()` to `onload`. Try passing `img.onload = loaded`;

Like [this (JSFiddle Here)](http://jsfiddle.net/KEGf6/).

```
var imageReady = false;
img = new Image(); 
img.onload = loaded;
```

And one more thing, I would suggest you to set the onload before the src.
I dont know how the browsers do the load internally, but MAYBE, it can load too fast the image and you will sent the onload after the load. Is that possible? dont know.

**Edit**

Yes, its better also to associate the callback `img.onload = loaded` before setting the `src` value. Just tested and if the Image is in cache, it may call the `onload` before you associate it.

Comment: thank you very much. But why you have to pass it like this: loaded and not like this: loaded():

Comment: Its a callback function. When you do `= loaded()` you are calling the function loaded and setting its return to the `onload`. But what you want is to give a function to the img so it can execute when the image is ready.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your `loaded()` function and assigning `img.onload` to the return value of that function instead of assigning `img.onload` to your function.  Try changing your assignment to:

```
img.onload = loaded;
```

Also, I'm not sure I see the point of your `imageLoaded` flag.